# How can I spoof a UK caller ID from the US?

Tags: telephony, sip

I own several phone numbers in the United Kingdom that my UK customers can call to reach my business in the US. When we call UK customers from our US-based phones, we want the UK customers to see our UK phone number rather than our US phone number.

What is the simplest way to transform the caller ID that will be seen on a UK-based phone such that it appears as a UK number? Is there a way to achieve this with some sort of proxy?

Comment: It's going to depend a lot on your software/hardware and your SIP provider.  In general there's nothing stopping you from generating whatever caller-ID number you want when originating a call on a SIP trunk but how that's accomplished varies greatly by switch/gateway just as the way in which messages need to be formatted will vary based on the software in use by your provider.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your PSTN provider.  Some will allow you to put anything in the 'calling number' parameter during call setup.  Usually though, they will filter out spam.  However, you might be able to work with them, or maybe search for a provider that will allow this.

Alternatively, route the traffic through the UK - for real.